# Displaying days and dates of 2 months

Tags: php, jquery

I want to **display day and date** starting from the **current month** up to the **next two months** like this:

```
tue  wed  thu
1    2    3
Aug  Aug  Aug
```

**And so on**, up to October in this case (2 months).

How can this be done with PHP and JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
<?php

$from = new \DateTime();
$to = new \DateTime('+2 months');

for ($from; $from < $to; $from->modify('+1 day')) {
    echo $from->format('D d M').PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
Wed 30 Aug
Thu 31 Aug
Fri 01 Sep
Sat 02 Sep
Sun 03 Sep
Mon 04 Sep
Tue 05 Sep
...
Mon 30 Oct
```

If you want your display, you can do:

```
<?php

$from = new \DateTime();
$to = new \DateTime('+2 months');

$dates = [];
for ($from; $from < $to; $from->modify('+1 day')) {
    $dates[] = [
        'numerical day' => $from->format('d'),
        'text day' => $from->format('D'),
        'text month' => $from->format('M'),
    ];
}

echo implode(' ', array_column($dates, 'text day')).PHP_EOL;
echo ' '.implode('  ', array_column($dates, 'numerical day')).PHP_EOL;
echo implode(' ', array_column($dates, 'text month')).PHP_EOL;
```

Will output:

```
Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon
 30  31  01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
Aug Aug Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Sep Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct Oct
```